# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<>'

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ2SQL: Cannot convert IQueryable<> to IOrderedQueryable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732236/linq2sql-cannot-convert-iqueryable-to-iorderedqueryable-error)

I having this error in the searchString of my controller..

here is my codes:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{ 
    posts = posts.Where(post => post.Body == searchString);
}
```

I'm using this codes for my search in my Index.
Did I declare something wrong here or something? I already tried googling but didn't find a clear answer. Thanks in advance for anyone who could help me..

Comment: What is post and how did you declare/use it ?

Comment: This thread looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732236/linq2sql-cannot-convert-iqueryable-to-iorderedqueryable-error What datatype is posts?  Where did it come from? Are you doing any sorting (orderby) on it anywhere?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you used an implicit `var` declaration for `posts` in a query that has an `OrderBy`. If you replace it with

```
IQueryable<Post> posts = someSource.Where(cond).OrderBy(/*the culprit*/);
```

the error should go away.

Comment: whoa.. Yeah you're right dude.. Your answer works perfectly for me. It works.. Thanks :).. !!

Answer (score 6):

Your `posts` variable seems to be of type `IOrderedQueryable<Post>` but you are assigning it a  `IQueryable<Post>`. I see 2 ways to resolve this, either modify your variable type to be `IQueryable<Post>` or sort your query like this:

```
posts = posts.Where(post => post.Body == searchString)
    .OrderBy(post => post.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

`posts` is `IOrderedQueryable` and the call to where is returning an `IQueryable`. Why don't you explicitly declare the variable and see if it fixes the issue.